# Making Ajax Form Use Native Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have a form that uses Ajax to send a serialized forms data to send to a php file called contact-submit

i know i should wrap the contents of that page in a function...and add it to the functions.php file

i plan on calling the function MyContactForm

but i dont know the proper syntax to serialize the form and post the data to the function

heres what i have so far ...*keep in mind i left out the form fields...because we are focusing on the script part of this ...if the form is serialized...should grab everything

html

```
<form id="contactform" action="<?php echo home_url('contact-submit'); ?>" method="post">

<input class="textbox required" type="text" name="name2" id="name" value="Your Name" />

<input class="submit" value="Send" type="submit" alt="Send message" name="submit" /> 

</form>
```

script

```
    jQuery("#postform").validate();

    var AjaxSubmit = function(){
        var btnText=jQuery('#contactform .submit').val();
        // inform client that data is been sent:
        jQuery('#contactform .submit').val('Sending...');
                jQuery('#contactform .submit').attr('disabled', true);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: jQuery('#contactform').attr('action'),
            data: jQuery('#contactform').serialize(),
            // successful POST - display result in success div:
            success: function(msg){
                        jQuery('#contactform .form, #contactform .contacthead').slideUp(500,function(){
                        jQuery('#contactform div.success').removeClass('hiddne').fadeIn(500);
                });
            },  
            error: function(response) {
                jQuery('#contactform .submit').val(btnText);
                jQuery('#contactform div.error').html(response.statusText).slideDown(500);
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery("#contactform").validate({
        submitHandler: AjaxSubmit
    });
});
```

My Question is.....what is the proper syntax for serializing a form and passing the data to a php function?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get errors? Your code seems ok from what I can see.

Comment: i want it to use wordpress native ajax....because if it doesnt it has a conflict with a plugin i want to use

Comment: So you want us to refactor the code above to make it compatible with Wordpress? Again; what do you expect from the StackOverflow community?

Comment: no just to tell me what the proper syntax is for serializing data and sending to a function....i know the rest lol